# Multiple usages of ComImportAttribute in a single AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, com, appdomain

I have two libraries, as separate DLL's. These libraries don't ever reference each other directly, but there is a chance that they can exist in the same AppDomain.

This isn't an issue (it seems) until the use of `ComImport[...]` conflicts.

library1.file1.cs

```
namespace AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio.Interfaces
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid(ComIIds.DEVICE_ENUMERATOR_CID)] //BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E
    internal class MultimediaDeviceEnumeratorComObject
    {
    }
}
```

library2.file2.cs

```
namespace AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.Hooking.ComObjects
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
    internal class MultimediaDeviceEnumeratorComObject
    {
    }
}
```

library2.somefile.cs

```
public void GetObject()
{
    //throws unable to cast exception
    var enumerator = new MultimediaDeviceEnumeratorComObject();
}
```

Exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio.Interfaces.MultimediaDeviceEnumeratorComObject' to type 'AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.Hooking.ComObjects.MultimediaDeviceEnumeratorComObject'.
```

It seems that the first usage of `ComImport` "fixes" itself, and any request to create an object with that CLSID in the future returns that first used type.

This seems like a huge oversight, and could cause unexpected issues when interfacing a third party library from different places in code.

Does anyone know of a way to resolve this issue? I have a work around by creating an unknown instance, and casting it directly to an implemented interface. But it seems hacky.

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E"))) as IMultimediaDeviceEnumerator;
```

EDIT:
Source (if it helps): https://github.com/xenolightning/AudioSwitcher

The current working problem is in the AudioSession branch

Comment: These are 2 unrelated classes. You can't cast one to another. BTW, your real code is likely not `var enumerator = new MultimediaDeviceEnumeratorComObject`, please post the exact code.

Comment: I know they are unrelated. There is no direct cast between the two classes. There cannot be, as the two projects don't reference each other. That is the exact code, and exactly what it is causing the issue.

Comment: Can you please link directly to that part of code on Github?

Comment: https://github.com/xenolightning/AudioSwitcher/commit/27c7d8a1dc7ed815cd3deaa9254c269889f8ef2d Has all relevant details. The code is currently commented out in DefaultDeviceHook.cs

Comment: So line 105 is throwing? Not some other between 105 and 119?

Comment: This cannot work for regular .NET classes either, the type identity of a .NET type is not just the namespace and type name, it also includes the assembly it came from.  You'll have to rejigger your projects, put all the interop types in a single project that everybody else can reference.  You are reinventing the NAudio library btw, it already has these declarations.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Yes it's throwing on 105, not other piece of code.

Comment: @HansPassant That could be an option. However, it seems fairly ridiculous if you include two "conflicting" libraries you can cause internal errors of another entirely separate library. It's not a reinvention of NAudio, I know of NAudio; and it doesn't handle multi threading for com objects efficiently, nor does it offer an intuitive way of querying devices. It also has a tendency to leak handles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using `ComImport` and creating a ComObject "Factory" instead. Code for said factory is below. It allows loading of the same com type in different namespaces without any conflicts.

```
internal static class ComObjectFactory
{

    public static IMultimediaDeviceEnumerator GetDeviceEnumerator()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(ComIIds.DEVICE_ENUMERATOR_CID))) as IMultimediaDeviceEnumerator;
    }

}
```